# What's the nearest 5e implementation of Kratos' Leviathan axe?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In God of War 4, Kratos uses an axe called Leviathan that he can attack with, throw and recall (which can cause damage to enemies on its return to his hand).

What is the nearest similar weapon in D&D 5e? Do recallable weapons cause any balance issues?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Take a look at the [Dwarven Thrower](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dwarven-thrower)

> When you hit with a ranged attack using this weapon, it deals an extra 1d8 damage or, if the target is a giant, 2d8 damage. Immediately after the attack, the weapon flies back to your hand.

It can be found in the Dungeon Master's Guide on page 167

Unfortunately, it does not deal damage on the return, but if you have Extra Attack, you could simply pretend it did. Your second attack would literally be a second throw, but you can narrate that as it dealing damage on the way back.

### But that is a hammer and/or I'm not a dwarf

Talk to your DM about changing the specifics of the weapon (a battleaxe is fundamentally the same as a warhammer). It won't change balance too much.

Changing the bonus against giants to another creature type for flavor reasons (with DM permission) would also not make a substantial difference (just be wary about the varying power of certain creature types depending on the proportion of enemies in your setting/campaign).

*Note: a variant that doesn't have the dwarf limitation and has a different creature type for the extra damage MIGHT be bumped up to Legendary rarity by your DM. Just making you aware ahead of time*

Comment: dwarf hammer is already '2 handed' in that it has the Versatile(d10) option, and a battle axe variant 'Dwarven Thrower' would have the same Versatile(d10) trait as well.. Just saying.

Comment: @JackChance valid, I'll revise a bit

Comment: Even if the chosen creature type *is* the primary antagonist of the campaign, that doesn’t make that choice any more “powerful” than the stock *dwarven thrower* is in a campaign that’s against giants.

Comment: @KRyan fixed to be more general

Comment: @KRyan: On the other hand, Giants probably have more HPs than Feys, so it may be worth reducing the bonus proportionally to match the hit die used by the new foe.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Assuming the same level, they presumably have something else—better AC maybe, or magical defenses, or just being more dangerous and so needing to die faster. I probably would not make such modifications, unless I thought the original value was wrong in the first place, even for giants.

Answer (score 12):

## If you're an Eldritch Fighter, you could use a hand-axe.

At level 3, Eldritch Fighters gain the **Weapon Bond** feature.

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself, you
>   can't be disarmed of that weapon unless you are
>   incapacitated. If it is on the same plane of existence,
>   you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your
>   turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.

Bonding with a Hand-Axe, for example, lets you throw the axe, and then re-summon it back. This causes no damage when re-summoning it though.

Advantages over the Dwarven Thrower are that this requires no specific magical weapon, there is no race requirement, it can be done with an Axe (or any other enchanted throwable weapon), and can be done reliably from 3rd level onwards. Disadvantages are that it is a class feature, and you can only summon the weapon back with a bonus action.